# jScrollPane not working for full page scrallbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

i'm trying to implement jScrollPane in my whole page to change scrollbar of page,but it doesn't working.

my code is as css:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main-wrap {
    height: 100%;
}
```

jquery:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     "use strict";
  $('#main-wrap').jScrollPane();
  });
```

and html:

```
  <div id="main-wrap">
     all other contents...
  </div>
```

and all the things that are given in the jScrallPane.

the problem is:
scrollbar appears but the page doesn't scroll directly with pinch scroll or mouse scroll.

please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to specify a width for #main-wrap in css

```
#main-wrap{
width:400px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: iam having a jscrollpane problem in IE10, horizontal bars always shows